# How can I run a VB script having arguments using cmd prompt using tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a VB script which converts a csv file into xls. When this VB script is run in cmd prompt, it requires 2 arguments: path of csv file which is needed to be converted, and path of xls file where it is to be saved:

```
D:\csv2xlx.vbs D:\sample.csv D:\converted.xls
```

I want this to be executed using tcl by calling cmd prompt. When I write:

```
exec cmd.exe /c start D:\csv2xls.vbs D:\sample.csv D:\converted.xls
```

It gives an error. Can anybody suggest what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem you've probably got is that those backslashes are getting interpreted by Tcl instead of getting passed through. The fix is to use forward slashes and then process the filenames with `file nativename` during the `exec`:

```
exec cmd.exe /c start \
        [file nativename D:/csv2xls.vbs] [file nativename D:/sample.csv] \
        [file nativename D:/converted.xls]
```

Alternatively, use `\\` instead of `\` in those filenames. Or put them in braces.

```
exec cmd.exe /c start D:\\csv2xls.vbs D:\\sample.csv D:\\converted.xls
```

```
exec cmd.exe /c start {D:\csv2xls.vbs} {D:\sample.csv} {D:\converted.xls}
```

Answer (score 1):

My machine no longer have VBScript on it, so I cannot test this out. Try:

```
exec cscript.exe D:\\csv2xls.vbs D:\\sample.csv D:\\converted.xls
```

**Update**: make double backslashes per Donal's suggestion.